# Installing libqxt VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4.7, installation, libqxt

Sorry if I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this sort of stuff, but thanks anyway.
Basically I've managed to install QT4.7 properly and it works and compiles stuff.  (I'm using it conjunction with vs2010).  However, I wanted to try something that requires libqxt.  Unfortunately [this](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide) seems to be the only installation guide out there.  And I'm really *not* getting it.  It mentions this little bit:

"configuration

Make sure qmake is in your PATH and run"

I think this is where I'm getting tripped up.  Is this the qmake the same one I used for QT4.7?  (If this is the case I shouldn't have to change anything right?  It ought to look like this: "c:\Qt\4.7\bin".  Which is added by going to > 
Control Panel|System|Advanced|Environment variables menu.  And which is already there from installing qt4.7)

Or is there a new qmake for libqxt somewhere?  Am I understanding the term PATH incorrectly?

In any case right now clicking on configure.bat just echoes back "searching" and then closes before I can read what else it says.  Would I be better off just opening a cmd prompt and cd'ing to the libqxt directory and running the configure file from there?

If anyone knows of an alternate install libqxt tutorial somewhere that'd probably helpful to me as well.  Thanks to anyone who can take a minute to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hmmm...so I played around with it and tried using the vs cmd prompt and everything seemed to work, right now I'm not sure where I should be adding "     CONFIG  += qxt
     QXT     += core gui" to the .pro file.  I assume somewhere in my .vcxproj file?

Comment: Basically just decided to use the boost library instead of libqxt for what I needed.  Forgot I asked this here as no one answered.  Guess the question is pretty much at the end of its life.